# Deploy a WCF workflow service Application

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have created a "WCF workflow service Application". as of now, i press F5 and run the application. after which the service will be up and running. then i ping this service using `SoapUI` ( I have loaded the `wsdl` in the `soapui`)

How do i host/deploy this "WCF workflow service Application". ( I dont want to press F5 to up the service basically).

I have tried using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service) link.
But it is not related to "WCF workflow service Application"

Comment: gonna deploy at local ?

Comment: Actually in a windows 2003 server(IIS-v 6.0) and a WIndows 7 desktop(IIS-v7.5).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to publish the Service , you can try the following screens,for your reference check these links :

1. [How to host wcf service in IIS 7 or 7.5](http://dotnetmentors.com/how-to-host-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx)
2. [creating WCF 4.0 Service and Hosting in IIS 7.5](http://debugmode.net/2010/09/07/walkthrough-on-creating-wcf-4-0-service-and-hosting-in-iis-7-5/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is cool. One problem is i dont have a svc file in my application which is of the type "WCF workflow service Application".

Comment: as of now we use the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe" to run/start the service

Comment: my attempt was to give a light on the issue you face through some screens and ref for more, so that you can build from there